# Problems login in to a website in python

Tags: python, authentication, web, urllib2, html

I've been trying to connect python with http/https sites and I came across urllib and urllib2.
After some research I could create a website login but it seems that I'm doing something wrong, I tried with different webpages but I can't do it with any.
There is the code I've been working on:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

#guardar cookies
cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()

#crear opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies))

user = raw_input("Introdueix el teu nom d'usuari: ")
contra = raw_input("Introdueix la teva pass: ")

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'login' : user,'password' : contra})
sessio = opener.open('http://streamcloud.eu/login.html', login_data)

#en teoria ja esta logejat a partir d'aqui

print "La URL accedida es:",sessio.geturl()

#tanquem la web
sessio.close()
```

The form of the website is this one:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://streamcloud.eu/" class="proform" name="FL">
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://streamcloud.eu/?op=upload">

<p>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" style="font-style: normal;" name="login" value="deuseux" class="text_field" />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" style="font-style: normal;" name="password" class="text_field" />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" class="button blue medium" value="Submit">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

The login form is in this webpage: http://streamcloud.eu/login.html while the action of the form is in http://streamcloud.eu, maybe there's where I'm doing something wrong?
If I put a print sessio.read() I can clearly see that I'm not logged in

Does anyone see something wrong with the code?
Thanks!

ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that you do a GET not a POST

Comment: You might find this related answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20926348/1382251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your English is fine :)

There are 2 other hidden input fields on the form which look like they need to be submitted with your login and password. These are:

```
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://streamcloud.eu/?op=upload">
```

I'd guess that `op=login` is required, not sure about the `redirect=...` - maybe you don't need that. Anyway, try changing your data to the following and see if you get any further:

```
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'login' : user, 'password' : contra, 'op' : 'login', 'redirect' : 'http://streamcloud.eu/?op=upload'})
```

Comment: that solved the problem, thanks! although
sessio = opener.open('http://streamcloud.eu/login.html', login_data)
had to be changed to
sessio = opener.open('http://streamcloud.eu/', login_data)

Comment: Yes, of course, you need to post the form data to the right URL, this being `http://streamcloud.eu/`. The site doesn't seem to support https.